# UIWebView crashes when app resumes from background

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsrunloop

I've noticed constant reproducible crash that occurs in a UIWebView:
Here the stack trace:

```
Incident Identifier: 4729DA31-A946-436D-97AC-EB3C8746E0FF
CrashReporter Key:   92eabebd7d2b07f27dde132a3c28d6bb7cf92df4
Hardware Model:      iPad3,6
Process:         ... [3120]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/10173A06-48D0-48F7-A832-9AC6961B045D/...app/...
Identifier:      ...
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-09 19:07:31.997 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  2

...

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
    Thread 2 Crashed:
    0   WebCore                         0x3772a03a WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 130
    1   WebCore                         0x37729f86 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 62
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x31741854 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x317414fe __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 270
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x31740172 __CFRunLoopRun + 1226
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x316b3238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x316b30c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
    7   WebCore                         0x37697390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a530de _pthread_start + 306
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a52fa4 thread_start + 4
```

Occurs with following steps:

1. Make UIWebView load the request (NSURLRequest)
2. Send app to background before the request is loaded
3. Wait a few minutes
4. Resuming the app from background will crash with the exemplified stack trace
   information.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Any help is very much appreciated!

**EDIT:** 
Code used to perform the request

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

My UIViewController is also a delegate of the UIWebView and I implement the following methods:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

The app crashed before any of those methods is invoked.

Comment: UIWebView always crashes if its running on a secondary thread. and what i understand is that when the app is resumed from background, the WebView starts running in secondary thread instead of main thread so it crashes. 

If you can post the code you r using then we can identify this clearly

Comment: @AhmedZ. I've added more information.

Comment: Sunny has given the solution.. check below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for resolving this one you can add notification and when app going to background process at that time pass the nil value to web view.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

or place below code in `applicationDidEnterBackground` method it freezes the all the tasks untill comes to `foreGround` process.

```
UIApplication *app = application;


    [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Synchronize the cleanup call on the main thread in case
        // the task actually finishes at around the same time.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //            if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            //            {
            //               // [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
            //               // bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            //            }
        });
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task.


        // Synchronize the cleanup call on the main thread in case
        // the expiration handler is fired at the same time.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this approach and it still crashes. Do I need to put something in beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "at that time pass the nil value to web view." Pass nil for delegate?